# How do I find a pixel that is NOT a certain color?

Tags: autohotkey

[AutoHotkey's `PixelSearch`](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/PixelSearch.htm) allows one to search for a pixel of a certain color in an (X1,Y1)..(X2,Y2) rectangle.

But I want to find any pixel that *isn't* a certain color, *i.e.* given a background color, I want to detect when any other color comes up in the foreground.

Is there a way to do this using the built-in `PixelSearch`, or other built-in functions?

Answer (score 1):

If you have some control over the background color, perhaps you can use PixelSearch's `variation` parameter.

If your background color is black, search for a **white** pixel with variation 254. PixelSearch should return any pixel that isn't black.

**This code searches for any pixel other than BLACK** (untested)

```
White := 0xFFFFFF
PixelSearch OutputVarX, OutputVarY, X1, Y1, X2, Y2, %White%, 254
```

If your background is midtone gray (0x7F7F7F), try searching for black *and* white with variation 127. Again, I haven't tested this.  Maybe the variation should be 126 or 63.  You might have to engage in some trial and error since the behavior of the variation parameter isn't comprehensively documented.

Comment: That's pretty clever. But yeah, since my background color can be all kinds of colors, like green, yellow, olive, etc. the generalization of the variation math seems a little tricky.

Comment: @AndrewCheong so maybe find out the background color inbefore with a seperate `pixelSearch`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use PixelGetColor to look at an individual pixel. The instruction tells you the color of the pixel at location x, y. An If command determines whether the pixel is  0x9D6346 or not.

Using PixelGetColor in a Loop allows you to test a range of pixels, one at a time by incrementing x, y or both.

And yes the proper order is BGR not RGB. A look at the help file confirmed that. :)

Something is happening to change the color. Perhaps you can look for another way to detect the change on the screen. Is the change of color due to another window or message becoming active? If so there are a number of commands you can use to determine what is appearing on the screen.

The windows spy is good at determining the names of pop up messages. Even if they have the same name as an existing window you can determine which is which  by the text included or excluded.

A change of the position of a particular window may be enough to detect the change you are looking for.

Perhaps a bit more detail describing what you are trying to detect will help. It would at least, confirm we are in the same ballpark.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot think of a reliable way to solve this with only built-in functionality. However, you could write it yourself with help of the external `GDI+`-library.

```
backgroundColor = 0x644E37
pToken := GDIP_StartUp()
pBitMap := GDIP_BitmapFromScreen()
while(a_index <= a_screenWidth) {
    w := a_index
    while(a_index <= a_screenHeight) {
        h := a_index
        ARGB := GDIP_GetPixel(pbitmap, w, h)
        RGB := ARGBtoRGB(ARGB)
        if(RGB != backgroundColor) {
            msgbox, % "found pixel at " w ", " h
        }
}
GDIP_DisposeImage(pBitMap)
GDIP_Shutdown(pToken)

return

ARGBtoRGB( ARGB ) {
    VarSetCapacity( RGB,6,0 )
    DllCall( "msvcrt.dll\sprintf", Str,RGB, Str,"%06X", UInt,ARGB<<8 )
    Return "0x" RGB
}
```

**untested**

Allegedly, this `gdip_bitmapFromScreen()` is actually *faster* than `pixelSearch`.

[source](https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/71728-gdi-library-pixelsearch/?p=454894)

Answer (score 0):

This pixel search worked for me to find any color other than white:

```
Search for black (0x000000),
if pixel not found
search for red (0xFF0000),
if pixel not found
search for lime (0x00FF00),
if pixel not found
search for blue (0x0000FF),
if pixel not found, the only color is pure white.
```

I Set all these to have a variation of 254. A variation of 255 finds everything, including white. I used lime instead of green because the official color called green has a green value of 128, while lime has a green value of 255 (red 0, green 255, blue 0). Seems that just searching for black usually finds NOT white, but sometimes you'll need to work your way down the list. This informs me whether or not there is ANY variation of ANY color other than white, including colors so close to white that I can't see them (when on a white background).

You might have to do a little math and/or experimentation for other colors, but I don't see why this method wouldn't work. I used fast RGB mode and window coordinates. Also I found helpful information here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_colors

Answer (score -1):

As a relative novice I hate to do this. :)

Right out of PixelSearch in the help file.

PixelSearch, Px, Py, 200, 200, 300, 300, 0x9d6346, 3, Fast

if ErrorLevel

```
MsgBox, That color was not found in the specified region.
```

else

```
MsgBox, A color within 3 shades of variation was found at X%Px% Y%Py%.
```

Understanding of hexadecimal and how the number applies to the color is necessary.

Color is expressed as a hexadecimal number. In this case 9d6346 and is broken down into three parts. I seem to recall 9d is the value for red, 63 for green, and 46 for blue. Those three numbers can range between  Hex 00 to Hex FF  (Decimal 0 to 255).

Variation is expressed as a Decimal number is the amount of allowable range in the search color

9D range being 9b to 9f. 63 = 61 to 66, 46 = 44 to 69. Depending on whether the search number is taken in or not my range could be out by 1.

If all else fails Google hexadecimal

Similar possibilities with PixelGetColor followed by a variety of If statements

Be prepared for a very wide variation. Some apps intermingle several distinctly different colors to achieve a desired color.

Comment: Actually I believe AHK defaults to BGR notation rather than RGB, unless a flag is set. In any case, I'm not sure how this helps my case though. Say my background color is 0x9d6346. How do I PixelSearch for whether there exists a pixel NOT of that color? Variation _includes_ the color.